# In Azure templates repository, is there a way to mention repository for a filePath parameter of azure task 'pythonScript'?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a template repository for build pipelines say 'azure-templates-repo', I have python task template as mentioned below:

```
steps:
- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filepath'
    scriptPath: 'python_test.yml' #this is located on repo: 'azure-templates-repo'
```

My question is on scriptPath, when I use this template in a build pipeline `azure-pipeline.yml` in a repository `my-great-app`, azure attempts to find the file in `my-great-app` instead where it really located `azure-templates-repo`.

So, Is there a way to mention repository for a filePath parameter of azure task 'pythonScript'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use a template in a pipeline, you are only consuming the .yml template file, not the entire repository that contains the template. So by default no other additional files (besides the template itself) that may exist in the template repository will be available when the primary pipeline is composed.

If you need access to scripts or other files that exist in your template repository you will need to use the checkout task and actually checkout the template repository.

`- checkout: git://MyProject/MyTemplateRepo`

One thing to be aware of if you go down the path of checking out multiple repositories is that it will cause the structure of your `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` to [change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#checkout-path). In practice this can cause pain as you have to update any tasks that expected your primary repository location to be at the root of `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`.

That mutation of the `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` might not be a big deal for you for new pipelines. It can turn into a pain if you have lots of pipelines that you want to consume a new template in, that require supporting scripts.

One option is to package the supporting template scripts, and publish them to an internal package feed. Then within your template block pull down the required script as a package. I have used this strategy before with templates that needed supporting powerShell scripts. We pipeline those scripts and publish them as a [universal packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), then consume them at the template level.

Comment: i am grateful that you didn't only provide solution but also their evaluation. I like the later option of using packages.