# how to template python tasks in azure devops pipelines

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have two repositories A & B.

Azure Repository A - Contains a python app
Azure Repository B - Contains .yml templates and .py scripts I want to run in the .yml templates

According to the documentations.. I cannot do this because when I expand the template into the calling repository A's pipeline.. it will be like a code directive and just inject the code.. it will not know or care about the .py files in the respoitory.

What are my options without doing all my .py routines as `inline` ?

**Azure Repo A's Pipeline Yaml file**

```
trigger: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: my_project_a_pipeline
    source: trigger_pipeline
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - master
  repositories:
  - repository: template_repo_b
    type: git
    name: template_repo_b
    ref: main

stages:
- template: pipelines/some_template.yml@template_repo_b
  parameters:
    SOME_PARAM_KEY: "some_param_value"
```

**Azure Repo B's some_template.yml**

```
parameters:
- name: SOME_PARAM_KEY
  type: string

stages:
- stage: MyStage
  displayName: "SomeStage"
  jobs:
    - job: "MyJob"
      displayName: "MyJob"
      steps:
        - bash: |
            echo Bashing
            ls -la
          displayName: 'Execute Warmup'
        - task: PythonScript@0
          inputs:
            scriptSource: "filePath"
            scriptPath: /SOME_PATH_ON_REPO_B/my_dumb_script.py
            script: "my_dumb_script.py"
```

Is there an option to wire in the .py files into a completely separate repo C... add C to resources of B templates.. and be on my way ?

EDIT:

I can see [In Azure templates repository, is there a way to mention repository for a filePath parameter of azure task 'pythonScript'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60231277/in-azure-templates-repository-is-there-a-way-to-mention-repository-for-a-filepa) but then how do I consume the python package.. can I still use the PythonScript task ? sounds like I would then need to call my pip packaged code straight from bash ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. how to pip install py files in azure devops pipelines.. using azure repositories.. via a template in the same repo

just add a reference to yourself at the top of any template

In the consuming repo

```
  repositories:
  - repository: this_template_repo
    type: git
    name: this_template_repo
    ref: master
```

then add a job, referencing yourself by that name

```
    - job: "PIP_INSTALL_LIBS"
      displayName: "pip install libraries to agent"
      steps:
        - checkout: this_template_repo
          path: this_template_repo
        - bash: |
            python3 -m pip install setuptools
            python3 -m pip install -e $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/somepypimodule/src --force-reinstall --no-deps
          displayName: 'pip install pip package'
```